# Prevent user from using ExternalLoginSignIn

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have a group of users who are our support staff.  They should not be allowed to use external login.    I can see that Identity can be configured to RequiredConfrmedEmail.

```
services.AddIdentity(config => config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true)
```

If the users email is not confirmed then signin will return `result.IsNotAllowed = false.`

So my question is there a way to configure sigin to a custom requirement that being Supporter = false on ApplicationUser?

My current solution:

```
 var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false, bypassTwoFactor: _configurationSettings.ThirdPartyLoginCanUse2Fa);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {

                // Todo can we make a policy that says supporter cant login using 3rd party apps.
                var user = await _userManager.FindByLoginAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey);
                if (!_configurationSettings.CanSupporterUse3RdPartyLogin && user.IsXenaSupporter)
                {
                    ErrorMessage = $"Xena supporter may not login with {info.LoginProvider} provider.";
                    _logger.LogInformation($"User {user.Id} is Xena supporter and may not login with {info.LoginProvider} provider.");
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
                }

                _logger.LogInformation($"User logged in with {info.LoginProvider} provider.");
                return (returnUrl == null)
                    ? RedirectToAction(nameof(Index), "Manage")
                    : RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
```

My current solution isn't ideal as technically the user is signed in and I am going to have to force log them out somehow.  Rather then just redirect them to login.

What i want is for `ExternalLoginSignInAsync` to return `result.IsNotAllowed` if `user.IsXenaSupporter` is true.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to extend the SignInManager.

```
public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser>
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private readonly ConfigurationSettings _configurationSettings;
        public ApplicationSignInManager(ConfigurationSettings configurationSettings, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor, IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser> claimsFactory, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor,
            ILogger<ApplicationSignInManager> logger, IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes) : base(userManager, contextAccessor, claimsFactory, optionsAccessor, logger, schemes)
        {
            _configurationSettings = configurationSettings;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public override async Task<SignInResult> ExternalLoginSignInAsync(string loginProvider, string providerKey, bool isPersistent, bool bypassTwoFactor)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindByLoginAsync(loginProvider, providerKey);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return SignInResult.Failed;
            }

            var error = await PreSignInCheck(user);
            if (error != null)
            {
                return error;
            }

            if (!_configurationSettings.CanSupporterUse3RdPartyLogin && user.IsXenaSupporter)
                return SignInResult.NotAllowed;

            return await SignInOrTwoFactorAsync(user, isPersistent, loginProvider, bypassTwoFactor);
        }
}
```

Now when a user signs in i check that they are allowed.